# Looking for recommendation of disc brake to replace Formula RX

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I have a relatively old hardtail MTB installed with Formula RX brake system and rotors SM-RT53 (160mm) / SM-RT53M (180mm). Now I have to replace the brake system and would like to have some advice.

To be honest I am overwhelmed by the huge amount of product selections. Could anyone give me some direction or specific recommendation?

It was OK with the Formula RX performance, and I would like to have something with similar price/performance classes.

However, robustness of brake system is more important for me than brake performance. I ride just tour on not really challenging trails, prefer ascending than downhill, and I may have trailers with a kid. And I would probably at first keep both SM-RT53(M) unchanged.

Are 4-pistons necessary? or if my rotors are suitable for those?

Comment: if you're riding with a trailer and maybe a kid, i'd definitely go with 4-pot brakes

Answer (score 4):

Choose a brake system from a top manufacturer. Sram, Shimano, Hope, Magura etc.

Judge the pricing that fits your budget and check availability.

See if reviews exist for the brakes you like.

All the top manufacturers have excellent reliability and serviceability now.

Your rotors should be fine if not too worn, they are standard sizes.